# How to add a literal prefix to a label using Geoserver's CSS Style

Tags: css, geoserver, sld

I have a layer of polygons, they have an attribute "Engine".  Let's say the values (all strings) are "1", "2", "3"
So I can get this to work easily:

```
* { fill: lightgrey; label: [Engine]; }
```

All the polygons are drawn and they are labeled "1", "2", and "3".

My question is - how do I label them "Engine 1", "Engine 2", and "Engine 3".  I simply want to prefix the [Engine] with some literal text.  Just concatenate the literal "Engine " with the value of the Engine attribute.

As a bonus - what if I want to concatenate literals and different attributes all into the same label?  I haven't found documentation on how to put anything but the value of an attribute or a literal into that label.  Not sure how to concatenate...

So this works as well (they all say "Engine" but you don't know which one...)

```
* { fill: lightgrey; label: 'Engine'; }
```

Ok, I finally type the whole question in, try one more thing, and it works! Just put the literal and the attribute next to each other - no concatenation operator required.

```
* { fill: lightgrey; label: 'Engine '[Engine]; }
```

Comment: why putting the answer is the question if you will answer the question later?

Comment: Well, the reader will have the answer quicker, I suppose...  I put it there when I was typing the question, then decided to answer officially myself for good measure.  Someone with editing rights may edit it some day if it annoys them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the literal and the attribute next to each other - no concatenation operator required.

```
* { fill: lightgrey; label: 'Engine '[Engine]; }
```